# Show that a convergent sequence in a finite-dimensional vector space has a unique limite

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

> Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $(\mathbb R^m, \|\cdot\|)$. Show that if $(x_n)\to x$ and $(x_n)\to y$ (with respect to $\|\cdot\|$ then we must have $x=y$.

It seems so simple yet I am unable to figure out how I would show it.

I know that if $$x_n \to x \quad \text{and} \quad  x_n\to y$$

then that means that $$\forall \epsilon_1,\epsilon_2>0 \quad \exists N_1,N_2\in \mathbb{N}: \quad \forall n>N_1,N_2$$

$$||x_n-x||<\epsilon_1 \quad \text{and} \quad ||x_n-y||<\epsilon_2$$

respectively.

This is where I get stuck. How can I combine these to show the limits are equal. Its a fairly intuitive idea but I am not sure how to write the proof.

My (probably unorthodox) intial idea was to set $$N=\max\{N_1,N_2\}$$

So that $$\forall n>N$$ both inequalities were satisfied

Then if I set $$\epsilon = \epsilon_1 + \epsilon_2$$

I could do $$||x_n-x||+||x_n-y||<\epsilon_1+\epsilon_2=\epsilon$$

This is where I am stumped.

Thanks!!

Comment: Your 2 ideas are excellent. But first write the second before the first. I.e. given $\epsilon>0,$ first choose e.g. $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2=\epsilon/2.$ The only 2 things you need to conclude are that $\|x-y|\le\|x-x_n\|+\|x_n-y\|,$ and that if $\|x-y\|$ is $<\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0,$ then it is $0.$

Comment: Check these search results: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=limit+is+unique

Comment: @AnneBauval Ah! I get it. Thank you, I forgot about the triangle rule and also positivity condition for norms. Thx for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

This is true more generally for Hausdorff spaces - topological spaces in which for any two distinct points there exist neighbourhoods of each which are disjoint from each other.

For if $x_n\to x$ and $x_n\to y$ with $x\ne y$, then there exist neighbourhoods $U$ of $x$ and $V$ of $y$ with $U\cap V=\varnothing$. Since $x_n\to x$, there exists $N_x$ such that $x_n\in U$ for $n\geqslant N_x$ and since $x_n\to y$, there exists $N_y$ such that $x_n\in V$ for $n\geqslant N_y$. Hence $x_n\in U\cap V$ for $n\geqslant\max\{N_x,N_y\}$, which is a contradiction as $U\cap V=\varnothing$, and so we must have $x=y$.